# When firefox prevents automatic redirection to another webpage, how do I find the distination page before allowing redirection?

Tags: firefox

When "Firefox prevented this page from automatically redirecting to another page" shows on a webpage, how can I find out the destination page before hitting "Allow"? Why would I not want to check this before allowing?

Comment: You can see on the bottom on the page, in the left side, the link where you could be redirected when you put the mouse over and does not click, when firefox sends this page, it's because the certificate that the page sends, it's outdate or doesn't match with the certificates allowed, but I don't know if this is your question, I think it's very ambigous